# A generalized quadratic loss and Newton iteration for Support Vector Regression, why doesn't it generalize well?

Tags: objective-functions, support-vector-machine

I'm comparing the results of an Newton optimizer for a modified version of SVM ( a generalized quadratic loss, similar to the one stated in:

[A generalized quadratic loss for SVM](http://www.frontiersinai.com/ecai/ecai2004/ecai04/pdf/p0628.pdf)

) with classic SVM^light for regression. The problem is that it's able to overfit the data (UCI Yacht data-set) but I can't reach the generalization results of SVM^light. I've tried several hyper-parameters grids. I'm solving the primal problem. I'll send you my code if you need it. Any suggestion?

Comment: I figured out I've not shuffled the whole data-set (training+validation+test).
Now it generalizes in a better way (at least on the UCI Yacht data-set)

Comment: I was wrong. I tried a different shuffle and the problem still persist.